# X, along with Y, "were" or "was"?

Tags: grammatical-number

I was interested in the following sentence which appeared in a [brief Tom Daschle's biography](http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/tom-daschle/gIQAoBBd9O_topic.html)  in The Washington Post, Politics, (WHO RUNS GOV).

> She, along with Mark Childress, *were* set to be Daschle's deputies at
>   the White House before he stepped down.

Can someone clarify if the fragment "She, along with Mark Childress, *were* set to" is ungrammatical, as I think it is?

I would reword *were* with *was* because I think that the subject of the sentence - obviously, in grammatical terms - is "She", not "She" and "Mark Childress", but I'm not sure on this correction.

More precisely, I'm not so sure that "She, along with Mark Childress" is equivalent to *She and Mark Childress* with regard to the effects on the grammatical numbers.

Answer (score 15):

You are correct. The subject of the sentence is "she", and thus the verb should be singular. It is true that, in a sense, the sentence is *logically* equivalent to "she and Mark ...", but "logically equivalent" and "grammatically equivalent" are two completely different things. The sentence is talking about "she" (whoever "she" is), and mentioning as a side note that Mark was also involved. It is not talking about "she and Mark".

Comment: Thank you Jay. combread ninja's comment had enormously confused me, adding confusion to confusion in my mind.

Answer (score 5):

From *The American Heritage Guide to Contemporary Usage and Style*:

> When a subject is followed by a conjoining prepositional phrase such
>   as *in addition to*, *as well as*, or *along with*, the verb should be
>   singular:
>
> Jesse as well as Luke likes jazz.
>
> The old school along with the playground is up for sale.

This is also what I learned. Most of the time, it's the syntactic *number* of the subject, not the underlying meaning, that dictates the verb agreement.

Another notable usage guide, *Practical English Usage*, 3rd ed, also says the same.