# "My brother along with his wife was present in the party" or "My brother along with his wife were present in the party"?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [X, along with Y, 'were'/'was'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70157/x-along-with-y-were-was)

Could someone tell which one is appropriate in the following sentence?

> My brother along with his wife **was/were** present in the party.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"My brother was present at the party" : Singular

"My brother and his wife were present at the party": Plural.

"My brother, along with his wife, was present at the party": Singular.

If you put in the commas to avoid doubt, then 'was' is right. If you use 'along with' as a substitute for 'and' with no commas, then 'were' is probably acceptable but will cause people to wonder, so best to avoid it.

Comment: Along with his wife, my brother ___ at the party.

Answer (score 4):

The subject of the sentence is *my brother*. *Along with his wife* is an adverbial, telling the reader more about him. It follows that the verb must agree with *my brother* and be singular. So, *My brother along with his wife was present in the party.*
The verb would, however, be plural if the subject was the coordinated *my brother and his wife*.