# Is the use of " were" correct in presence of "along"?

Tags: grammar

Is the following sentence, from a USA Today [news article online](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2014/10/28/ebola-emory-amber-vinson/18044545/), correct?

> Vinson, along with Nina Pham, **were** the two nurses at Texas Health
>   Presbyterian Hospital who contracted the virus while caring for Thomas
>   Duncan, a Liberian national who died of the disease on Oct. 8.

There is [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70157/x-along-with-y-were-or-was) on EL&U that targets the same topic, but it does not have an answer selected.

Comment: The error is in using the parenthetical clause, which cannot create such a mismatch. Needs rephrasing. But I guess journalists play with grammar all the time. Just fun!

Comment: @Kris Which one is the parenthetical clause? Thanks.

Comment: "along with Nina Pham" between the commas.

Comment: I think to correct *this particular sentence* I would write it as follows: "Vinson, along with Nina Pham, was one of the two nurses at Texas Health..." That aligns the verb to agree with the subject and still distinguishes that there are two people being discussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Vinson and Nina Pham, the two nurses at Texas Health Presbyterian Hospital contracted the virus while caring for Thomas Duncan, a Liberian national who died of the disease on Oct. 8.

Phrases such as "in addition to," "as well as," and "along with" do not mean the same thing as **"and."**

Reference: [When the subjects are joined by "and"](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/SubjectVerb.html)

Comment: Can you explain more thoroughly? Without following the link, this appears to just be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically wrong.

By saying 'along with Nina Pham' instead of 'and Nina Pham' and by surrounding the phrase with commas, the writer has turned the phrase into a parenthetical phrase. In other words, the rest of the sentence *should* make sense without this phrase. Except it doesn't. Without the phrase, it reads:

'Vinson were the two nurses at Texas Health...'

This is nonsense.

As Martin said, the sentence should say 'Vinson and Nina Pham were the two nurses...'. It would also be correct to say 'Vinson, along with Nina Pham, **was the nurse** at Texas Health...', although then you wonder who Nina Pham is.

More generally, if you have a main subject and a secondary subject in a sentence, the verb should agree with the main subject. A main subject can be separated from a secondary subject by commas, brackets or dashes, and by phrases like 'together with', 'along with', 'as well as'.

For example:

'Our **company**, along with three other companies, **is** representing the UK at a global event.'

**Sarah and Rachel**, and perhaps Pete, **are** in line for promotions this year.

Comment: +1 Thank you! "This is nonsense" -> That's what I thought as well, but having been posted at a major newspaper, I wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is better more concise English to say, "Vinson and Nina Pham were the two nurses..."

Comment: This is undoubtedly true, but I'm not sure it answers the question that was asked.